# Referring to child class in function inherited from parent

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6

I'm have method a that decorates a given array of objects:

```
class Vehicle {
  static fromArray(vals) {
    return vals.map((v) => { return new Vehicle(v); });
  }
}
```

...I would like to extend that to work on a series of child-classes:

```
class Boat extends Vehicle {
}

class Car extends Vehicle {
}

Car.fromArray([{name: 'volvo'}])  // should return Car objects, not Vehicle
```

What do I replace `Vehicle` with in the parent?  Or do I have to override `fromArray` in the child objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could slightly modify your code:

```js
'use strict'

class Vehicle {
  static fromArray(vals) {
    var constr = this; // <-- don't need this if you use an arrow function below
    return vals.map(function(v) { return new constr(v); });
  }
}

class Boat extends Vehicle {
}

class Car extends Vehicle {
  drive() { console.log('driving'); }
}

var base = Vehicle.fromArray([1])[0];
var car = Car.fromArray([1])[0];

car.drive();
//base.drive(); // <-- will throw exception
```

The key here is that for static methods, the `this` variable is set to the type itself, so you can `new this()` to create an object of the same type.

> Note: this is tested on Chrome (V8), so should work on Node / iojs, *BUT*, I'm not 100% sure this is according to spec.

Answer (score 1):

In static methods, the `this` context is typically the constructor function itself, so you can just use that instead of referring to your `Vehicle` explicitly:

```
class Vehicle {
  static fromArray(vals) {
    return vals.map(v => new this(v));
  }
}
```

Notice that static methods are not bound, so if you reference them as a callback or so you have to care about getting `this` right.

Comment: This doesn't look different then my answer except not having the full code. Did I miss something important?

Comment: @Amit: I've simplified the `map` callback significantly :-) The "full" code is hardly necessary for the answer. Also I used a bit different (imo better, precise) wording, though the gist is the same.

Comment: I used the non arrow function "verbose" code because arrow functions aren't supported on V8 without special flags.I did mention that it can be removed if an arrow function is used. I don't see that as an important addition, but obviously you have the right to disagree ;-)

Comment: @Amit: I just didn't care about V8 :-) The question is tagged ES6 (not V8), and the OP already uses arrow functions himself…